# Redirected page only shows order summary (authorize.net accepted host)

Tags: php, sdk, authorize.net

I am using the php sdk provided by authorize.net. The particular method is the accepted host method using a redirected page. 
1) The token is returned with I00001 Successful message
2) The page does not display anything but order summary at the top.
3) I also get the error below in the Chrome console.

I have been fighting this for over 2 weeks to no avail, any help you all can give me would be greatly appreciated.
Jim

ERROR MESSAGE IN CHROME CONSOLE:

payment:24 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

CODE USED:

```
function sdk_test()
 {
     //-----------------------------------------------------------
     //Create a merchantAuthenticationType object with authentication details
     //retrieved from the constants file
     //-----------------------------------------------------------
    $merchantAuthentication = new 
 AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();
    //$merchantAuthentication->setName(\SampleCodeConstants::MERCHANT_LOGIN_ID);
    $merchantAuthentication->setName($this->anobj->get_field('login'));
    //$merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey(\SampleCodeConstants::MERCHANT_TRANSACTION_KEY);
    $merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey($this->anobj->get_field('x_trans_key'));

    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    // Set the transaction's refId
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    $refId = 'ref' . time();
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    // Create the payment data for a credit card
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    $creditCard = new AnetAPI\CreditCardType();
    $creditCard->setCardNumber("4111111111111111");
    $creditCard->setExpirationDate("2038-12");
    $creditCard->setCardCode("123");
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    // Add the payment data to a paymentType object
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    $paymentOne = new AnetAPI\PaymentType();
    $paymentOne->setCreditCard($creditCard);
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    // Create order information
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    $order = new AnetAPI\OrderType();
    $order->setInvoiceNumber("10101");
    $order->setDescription("Golf Shirts");
  //-----------------------------------------------------------
    // Set the customer's Bill To address
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    $customerAddress = new AnetAPI\CustomerAddressType();
    $customerAddress->setFirstName("Ellen");
    $customerAddress->setLastName("Johnson");
    $customerAddress->setCompany("Souveniropolis");
    $customerAddress->setAddress("14 Main Street");
    $customerAddress->setCity("Pecan Springs");
    $customerAddress->setState("TX");
    $customerAddress->setZip("44628");
    $customerAddress->setCountry("USA");
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    // Set the customer's identifying information
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    $customerData = new AnetAPI\CustomerDataType();
    $customerData->setType("individual");
    $customerData->setId("99999456654");
    $customerData->setEmail("EllenJohnson@example.com");
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    // Add values for transaction settings
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    $duplicateWindowSetting = new AnetAPI\SettingType();
    $duplicateWindowSetting->setSettingName("duplicateWindow");
    $duplicateWindowSetting->setSettingValue("60");
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    // Add some merchant defined fields. These fields won't be
    // stored with the transaction,but will be echoed back in the response.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    $merchantDefinedField1 = new AnetAPI\UserFieldType();
    $merchantDefinedField1->setName("customerLoyaltyNum");
    $merchantDefinedField1->setValue("1128836273");
    $merchantDefinedField2 = new AnetAPI\UserFieldType();
    $merchantDefinedField2->setName("favoriteColor");
    $merchantDefinedField2->setValue("blue");
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    // Create a TransactionRequestType object and add the previous objects to it
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    $transactionRequestType = new AnetAPI\TransactionRequestType();
    $transactionRequestType->setTransactionType("authOnlyTransaction");
    $transactionRequestType->setAmount($amount);
    $transactionRequestType->setOrder($order);
    $transactionRequestType->setPayment($paymentOne);
    $transactionRequestType->setBillTo($customerAddress);
    $transactionRequestType->setCustomer($customerData);
    $transactionRequestType->addToTransactionSettings($duplicateWindowSetting);
  $transactionRequestType->addToUserFields($merchantDefinedField1);
    $transactionRequestType->addToUserFields($merchantDefinedField2);
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    // Assemble the complete transaction request
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    $request = new AnetAPI\CreateTransactionRequest();
    $request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);
    $request->setRefId($refId);
    $request->setTransactionRequest($transactionRequestType);
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    // Create the controller and get the response
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    $controller = new AnetController\CreateTransactionController($request);
    $response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse(\net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::SANDBOX);
    if ($response != null)
    {
        // Check to see if the API request was successfully received and acted upon
        if ($response->getMessages()->getResultCode() == "Ok")
        {
            // Since the API request was successful, look for a transaction response
            // and parse it to display the results of authorizing the card
            $tresponse = $response->getTransactionResponse();

            if ($tresponse != null && $tresponse->getMessages() != null)
            {
                echo " Successfully created transaction with Transaction ID: " .
                    $tresponse->getTransId() . "\n";
                echo " Transaction Response Code: " . $tresponse->getResponseCode() . "\n";
                echo " Message Code: " . $tresponse->getMessages()[0]->getCode() . "\n";
                echo " Auth Code: " . $tresponse->getAuthCode() . "\n";
                echo " Description: " . $tresponse->getMessages()[0]->getDescription() . "\n";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Transaction Failed \n";
                if ($tresponse->getErrors() != null)
                {
                    echo " Error Code  : " .
                        $tresponse->getErrors()[0]->getErrorCode() . "\n";
                    echo " Error Message : " .
                        $tresponse->getErrors()[0]->getErrorText() . "\n";
                }
            }
   }
        else
        {
            echo "Transaction Failed \n";
            $tresponse = $response->getTransactionResponse();

            if ($tresponse != null && $tresponse->getErrors() != null)
            {
                echo " Error Code  : " .
                    $tresponse->getErrors()[0]->getErrorCode() . "\n";
                echo " Error Message : " .
                    $tresponse->getErrors()[0]->getErrorText() . "\n";
            }
            else
            {
                echo " Error Code  : " .
                    $response->getMessages()->getMessage()[0]->getCode() . "\n";
                echo " Error Message : " .
                    $response->getMessages()->getMessage()[0]->getText() . "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo  "No response returned \n";
    }
    return $response;
 }
```

RETURNED PAGE SOURCE:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0">

<head id="Head1"><title>
    Secure Information
</title>
          <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
            <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
            new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
            'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
            })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-KFWQGNC');</script>
          <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
    <script src="https://sandbox-assets.secure.checkout.visa.com/checkout-widget/resources/js/integration/v1/sdk.js" type="text/javascript" > </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          var g_token = "null";
          var g_merchantData = null;
          var g_pageOptions = null;
          var g_paymentProfiles = null;
          var g_maxPaymentProfiles = false;
          var g_errorPanelMessage = "The page has timed out. Please go back to the beginning and try again.";
            var g_siteKey = "6Lc8tgYAAAAAAFfalsuPuIZ6bv_2dGT_Y9ZxURiK";
            var g_visaCheckoutUrl = "https://sandbox.secure.checkout.visa.com/wallet-services-web/xo/button.png";
        </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var g_EcheckEnabled = false;
var g_CreditEnabled = false;
  </script>
  <base href="./Scripts/v1/">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="PageOuter" id="divPageOuter">
    <div id="divPopupScreen" class="PopupScreen" style="display:none;"></div>
      <div class="Page" id="divPage">
      <div class="PageMain container" id="divPageMain container">

          <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
            <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-KFWQGNC"
            height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
          <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
          <app-accept-payment></app-accept-payment>

          <link href="styles.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.bundle.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>        

      </div>
      <div class="PageMainAfter"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _“The page does not display anything but order summary at the top”_ - meaning, the rest of the page you’d expect after that, down to the footer or whatever, is missing? Then go check the server-side error logs first of all, resp. enable proper PHP error reporting.

Comment: _“ERROR MESSAGE IN CHROME CONSOLE: payment:24 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token”_ - that is rather pointless info, no one here as any idea what your server-side code actually outputs. You’d have to show us the code the client receives as well, before that info is of any use.

Comment: The server is not mine, it belongs to authorize.net, if you want to see the page source glad to provide it.

Comment: So by _“2) The page does not display anything but […]”_ you are referring to a page that shows while _their_ domain shows in the address bar, not that of your own project? So the actual payment page, not whatever the user gets redirected back to after making their payment?

Comment: Correct, the process goes something like this:
1) call sdk_test...
2) then get a token from the site, which I believe encodes the  entire page
3) then redirect your current page with the token embeded
4) which they are supposed to return with the form hosted from their site 
    collect the payment information then they redirect after payment back to a URL you specify in the SDK

Comment: That result page contains an error message saying, _The page has timed out. Please go back to the beginning and try again._ Have you checked their documentation for what causes this?

Comment: So where is that actual redirect from your site to theirs happening?

Comment: Basically, they click a button on my page which does a post to their site
    ```html 
    <form name="jmdform" method="post" action="{$url}">
        <input type="hidden" id="redirectToken" name="token" value="{$token}" />
      
    </form>
```

Comment: And you have verified that this field actually contains a token, when you submit this form?

Comment: Yes the {$token} is replaced with a token which gets logged to syslog  during testing